# Manifest XML signature is not valid Error in Windows 7 VSTO

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, vsto, manifest

I have a Word VSTO application (.net 4.6.1) that I am installing via an InstalShield installer. It works fine on all the computers I've tested it on so far, but one particular computer is having problems trusting the vsto. It installs with no issues, but when run, the customization aren't there and we get an error in the event viewer saying
"the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened"
I've researched this and all the answers seemed to point to it being an issue with .NET 4.0 not trusting SHA256. However, the computer have the problem is a Windows 7 computer, with .NET 4.6.1 installed. I even installed 4.7.1 and still get the issue.

Are there any other reasons for this error that I can look at? I am using Visual Studio 2013 with InstallShield to create the build and sign the assembly with a third party certificate. I've actually tried signing it in SHA1 with a test certificate created from visual studio and it still gives the error.

Comment: it could be a locale issue... is this machine set up to use same locale as the others? are you using localized resources?

Comment: yes it's set to the same locale as other machines the vsto has worked on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. We had to install the [Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54251) on the computer with the issue. After that the vsto worked. worked.